# Swinject: migrating to assemblies

Tags: ios, dependency-injection, swinject

I'm using awesome [Swinject](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject) for DI in my project, but I'm using it without assemblies (by the time I've started using Swinject, there was no assemblies).

My current pattern of using `Containers` is:

```
class ParentContainer {

    private let container: Container

    init(parentContainer: Container?) {
        container = Container(parent: parentContainer)

        container.register....
    }

    func myTopLevelController() -> MyTopController {
        let controller = container.resolve....
        controller.container = self // controller holds its container
        return controller
    }

    func childContainer() -> ChildContainer {
        return ChildContainer(parentContainer: container)
    }

}


class ChildContainer {

    private let container: Container

    init(parentContainer: Container?) {
    ....
}
```

With that configuration:

- containers lives as long as they need to live (the only entity holding reference to them - VC, that could use dependencies)
- I could stop using/switch DI framework and replace `Container` even with manual building (my code doesn't know about any framework), as my code calls: `let topController = ParentContainer().myTopLevelController()`

Now I'm trying to apply `Assembly`. As far as I can understand, **my** containers now will conform to `AssemblyType` protocol. But I have some confusion:

1. Should I resolve instances through assembly, not through container?
2. What is the purpose of `func loaded(resolver: ResolverType)` method? should I retain resolver? Can it lead to retain cycle?
3. I'd like to have TopLevelAssembly, but still use Containers for leaf entitites. Is it possible to pass Assembly as a parent for a container? Or are there any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1. Should I resolve instances through assembly, not through container?***

It's up to you whether you use the assembly feature. It is used [to manage grouping of dependencies](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject/blob/master/Documentation/Assembler.md#modularizing-service-registration). Since it looks you already manage the groups of dependencies by `ParentContainer` and `ChildContainer`, I think you don't have to use assemblies.

People who have used [Typhoon](https://github.com/appsquickly/typhoon) might prefer the feature. People who have used another `register`/`resolve` type DI container might prefer organizing container structures by themself.

***2. What is the purpose of func loaded(resolver: ResolverType) method? should I retain resolver? Can it lead to retain cycle?***

It is called after all assemblies are applied to a container in order to do something that cannot run during `assemble` method of an `Assembly`. It is called by the system of Swinject like `viewDidLoad` of `UIViewController` called by the UIKit system. [The documentation about `loaded`](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject/blob/master/Documentation/Assembler.md#load-aware) or [a unit test](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject/blob/master/SwinjectTests/AssemblerSpec.swift) might help you understanding `loaded` function.

You shouldn't store the `resolver` parameter. (Actually I don't see usecases to store it because `Assembler` doesn't keep references to assemblies, which will be released after you instantiate `Assembler`. Even if you store it, no retain cycle is caused.)

***3. I'd like to have TopLevelAssembly, but still use Containers for leaf entitites. Is it possible to pass Assembly as a parent for a container? Or are there any other way to achieve it?***

I didn't catch your context about the TopLevelAssembly and leaf entities. I will be able to update my answer later if you add more details.

Here are some comments to the question parts: You cannot pass an `Assembly` instance because the initializer of `Container` is `init(parent: Container? = nil)`, which takes an instance of `Container`. Another way to achieve it might be just keeping the top level as `Container`. (Or I have to update Swinject to support the scenario.)

My answer might not be perfect but I hope it helps you implement the service locator pattern.

Comment: thanks for your answer and your lib! Just to make some clarification on 3. In reality my scheme is more complex, than described above. Let's say, I have AppContainer -> UserContainer -> ControllerContainer. The first one holds all system-wide services (api, db, etc..), the second one stored user related data, and the third one knows how to build specific controller.

I don't want all data to be dumped in AppContrainer (as it can be complicated) and I thought of Assembly as a horizontal grouping, but keep my data vertically structured same way. Is it possible?

Comment: Thank you for the context about the horizontal and vertical groupings. So far the assemblies of Swinject do not support mixing the horizontal and vertical groupings. The initializer of `Assembler` can take only `Container` type. If I add an initializer to take a parent `Assembler`, the feature can be added though I have to investigate the impact to existing code. I got the enough details from your comment, so we don't need the skype chat. You can remove your skype ID for your privacy.